# Make a List from a Tuple List on F#

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Lets say I have a tuple list. Just to make it easier to refer to, its a coordinates with an x and y values.

let test = [(1,34);(2,43);(3,21);(1,51);(2,98);(3,56);(1,51)]

I want to make another list using test so that if I only want value which has an x value of 1, it would return [34;51;51]

Comment: You need to *filter* the list first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to *filter* the list first to get tuples that have an x value of 1, then map the results to get the `y` value :

```
[(1,34);(2,43);(3,21);(1,51);(2,98);(3,56);(1,51)]
|> List.filter (fun (x,_)->x=1)
|> List.map snd
```

This returns :

```
[34;51;51]
```

Comment: You can use `choose` instead of `filter` and `map`: `list |> List.choose (fun (x, y) -> if x = 1 then Some(y) else None)`.

Comment: @Lee .. which may be shortened by matching against the literal `1`: `List.choose (function 1, y -> Some y | _ -> None)`