# F# List of Tuples

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have this tuple list:

```
test = [(1,2,3);(2,3,4);(3,4,5);(1,5,6);(2,6,7);(3,7,8);(1,8,9);(2,9,10);(3,10,11);(1,11,12)]
```

I have tried `test |> List.Filter (fun (x,_,_) -> x = 1)` to filter out the tuple which has 1 as the first element but the return would be `[(1,2,3);(1,5,6);(1,8,9);(1,11,12)]`

What can I add **test |> List.Filter (fun (x,*,*) -> x = 1) |> ??** so that it does one more steps and reduce the number of element in the tuples and get the desired result of `[(2,3);(5,6);(8,9);(11,12)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds very similar to your previous question ...

[Make a List from a Tuple List on F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727787/make-a-list-from-a-tuple-list-on-f)

you just replace your function

```
snd
```

by a function that returns what you want, here:

```
fun (_,x,y) -> (x,y)
```

Comment: @ Jeff_hk Sorry. I know the question is too similar but I couldn't figure out how I can do it. I'm trying to learn F# and still quite a beginner at it

Comment: sure no problem, but I think it would be easier to ask using your previous question. Good luck with it, it is a nice language !